# Exporting layers to different sheets of an Excel file

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, excel

I have two memory layers that I would like to write their attribute tables to the same Excel file but in different sheets. So far, I've managed to write the attribute tables to separate files using `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`.

```
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("memory_layer1")[0]
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("memory_layer2")[0]

# export to separate file
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1, 'path/file1.xlsx', 
    "utf-8", layer1.crs(), "XLSX", layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer2, 'path/file2.xlsx', 
    "utf-8", layer2.crs(), "XLSX", layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### On QGIS 3.10.3 or above

You can do that in this way:

```
# Prepare options for layer1
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "XLSX"
options.fileEncoding = "utf-8"
options.layerOptions = ["GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ"]
options.layerName = 'layer1'

# Export layer1
result, error_str = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(
    layer1,
    '/tmp/my_file.xlsx',
    QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
    options
)
print(result)

# Prepare options for layer2
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
options.layerName = 'layer2'

# Export layer2
result, error_str = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(
    layer2,
    '/tmp/my_file.xlsx',
    QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
    options
)
print(result)
```

The key is to open the file in **update** mode when exporting the second layer, i.e., to set `options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer`. See the full list of options [in the docs](https://qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsVectorFileWriter_1_1SaveVectorOptions.html)

---

### On QGIS 3.10.2 or below

You can use `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat()` in this way:

```
# Export layer
result, error_str = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    layer,
    '/tmp/my_file.xlsx',
    options  # See above how to set the options object
)
```

Comment: 'QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2' is present since QGIS 3.0.  This shouldn't be a problem as I'm using QGIS 3.8. However, I get an AttributeError, saying "type object 'QgsVectorFileWriter' has no attribute 'writeAsVectorFormatV2' ". I've tried a few imports into PyQGIS console, such as 'import qgis', 'from qgis.core import *', 'from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter' and 'from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2' (didn't like the syntax for this one), but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You need at least QGIS v3.10.3 to use `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2`. The other methods are deprecated.

Comment: What is the difference between using QgsProject.instance().transformContext() and QgsCoordinateTransformContext() in QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3? If I want to export the new layer in the same CRS from input layer, is it ok to use only QgsCoordinateTransformContext()?

Answer (score 1):

Some advanced format creation options can usually be found in OGR format specification: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/xlsx.html

There are no options suitable for your need but you can easily merge the files afterwards using `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file1='path/file1.xls'
file2='path/file2.xls'
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet_name='Sheet1')

outPath = 'merged.xls'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outPath, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet_from_1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet_from_2')
writer.save()
```